# Can I omit the object of a transitive verb?

Tags: transitivity

Is the sentences:"I eat" grammatical? Here, "eat" is transitive, but I don't use any object.

Regards

Comment: Yes, it's fine. "Eat" is a verb that can be transitive (_I eat fish_) or intransitive (_When I'm hungry, I eat_)

Comment: I think this is General Reference. Any dictionary will tell you that ***eat*** can be both transitive and intransitive.

Answer (score 2):

"Eat" is actually a verb that can be both transitive and intransitive.  There are many such verbs in English:

> I can't talk now, I'm driving.
>
> She's very serious about food and never talks when she eats.

However while most transitive verbs don't make sense without an object -- e.g.  "close", "join", "wear" -- nevertheless in some contexts the object is implied:

> I have to work late, I am closing tonight.

Here "closing" is the last shift who cleans up and makes sure the stop/store/restaurant/etc. is locked up.  So the sentence implies "close the shop".

> A. Girls aren't allowed in our club!
>   B. But I want to join!

Again, implied "join the club".